# Windows 2008 web app server -hardware planning help

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, web-hosting, capacity-planning

I am setting up a website on win2008/sql2008 (64 bit) on a dedicated server, which may get 50K to 100K users/visitors. Concurrent users at any time may be 1000 (max). Users will log in 4 to 6 times a month and spend 10 minutes (maximum) on the site for minimal data entry. There will be some reporting run at night. The site has no image transfer facilities, except for one member photo.

I am wondering if any of the following specs will be enough for the server.

1) Core i7-860- 8GB RAM, 1.5TB bandwidth

2) 2x 5420 - 8GB RAM - 5TB bandwidth.

How do I calculate bandwidth and server capacity utilization? Am I getting a much bigger box than needed with # 2.
The data entered by users is minimum. Users choose 10 to 15 drop down fields, type in a few numbers and click sybmit..

I am planning to get 100 MBPS port speed. Do I really need that much or will 10 MBPS be enough?

Comment: The only way you're going to know for sure is to simulate load using your application and API stack.

Answer (score 1):

> Concurrent users at any time may be
>   1000 (max).

Trivial amount unless you do obviously stupid things (like storing 400mb data in the session). Unless VERY active that is not a lot of pages per second.

> spend 10 minutes (maximum) on the site
>   for minimal data entry.

That is low activity, as people will NOT fill out a form in 0.1 seconds ;)

I would say both servers are ok. The bandwidth you have to calculate - we simply miss enough informatioon t oget that calculated. I suggest doing a test run with a handfull simulated users and measure bandwith utilization.

CPU and RAM should be plenty. This is PLENTY like in PLENTY PLENTY PLENTY.

I once did a dating site (heavy on images etc.) running on a dual Pentium (that is with ONE ore each, 120 Mhz or so) for web and data (2 machines) handling 300.000 sessions... in one hour.

Means: really depends on your programming.

Comment: Tomtom, please see updates on data entry and port. I am having a test server on a very low end machine (Atom).

Comment: 10mbs should be enough. We did that on a 34mbit link and did not use it up. If you have efficient bandwidth usage (no arge photos etc.) it should be enough.

Comment: tomtom, users will upload a photo,while registering. When the website loads, it will have a few images on each page (optimized gifs). So you think that I can go safely with 10MBPS and i7-860, if needed?

Comment: Depends. I would say NO. The problem is that if users upload 1-2mbyte large photos they clog up your bandwith easily. You will likely spike higher than 10mbps - not long, but delays MAY be recognizable. I would go with a 100mbit or higher link and a traffic plan... this allows you to handle spikes. Like 5 people uploading an image at pretty much the same time.